# Pan frame 360 degree video sdk navigating using 'Motion'

Tags: android, video, video-player, 360-degrees

I am working on Pan frame 360 degree video Android SDK and would like to navigate around the video using 'Motion' mode (using gyroscope). It is described in the [documentation](http://www.panframe.com/sdk/android/api/1.9.6/com/panframe/android/lib/PFNavigationMode.html). But, I was not able to get that working. Do I need to enable any specific permission. I was able to navigate the video using 'Touch'.

Comment: I am also concerned about this. Were you able to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is what i added into my manifest file

```html
<manifes>
  
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true" />
  
</mainfest>
```

But for me the problem was that both the phone and tablet in which I tested app do not have gyroscope. (only accelerometer). So if this is the case for you check if your devise has gyroscope. Tested on Galaxy 5s, it worked.

EDIT: To check if my devise has gyroscope or not I just looked at devise specification on the internet, and that's it.

Comment: Just to make your answer better, do you have any sample code for doing the check?

Answer (score 0):

check if your device support gyroscope with supportedNavigationMode function. see sdk docs